# how to convert Object into JSONObject

Tags: android, json, object, android-listview

I have a listview that is populated using the `JSONArray`. Then I added the context menu to my List.

Now I want to retrieve the values of the listitems on which the user selected ,so I used

```
 AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();       
 Object object=  list.getItemAtPosition(info.position);
```

now the problem is that `getItemAtPosition()` returns an Object . How Can I convert it into the relative **JSONOBject**?

Comment: You will have to make use of gson library to get the JSONObject from java.

Comment: if you fille the adapter with a JSonArray why do you try to cast it to JSONObject?

Comment: I filled my adapter to populate the ListView with JSONArray but then each row of the ListView is an JSONObject. I want to get just a row from the list . So JSONObject

Comment: Every line of the listview is a view. Can you post your adapter?

Comment: Ohh!! found out the problem here... I used HashMap in the adapter. I got my data from Jsonarray, parsed it into the hashmap and then added it to my adapter. So now instead of converting Object into JSONObject , I used HashMap. works Fine . Thanks EveryOne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();       
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) list.getItemAtPosition(info.position);
```

And no need for gson library here, since JSON is part from Android library `org.json.JSONObject` since Api 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your return value as JSONObject.

Comment: it gives a class cast exception.

Answer (score 0):

Because I used JSONArray and then I parsed it into corresponding HashMap , used it in my adapter. So the function getItemAtPosition was returning an HashMap in the form of an Object
problem with my code was that I was casting a HashMap Value into JSONObject so instead Of casting it into the JSONObject I used Hashmaps. 
   `HashMap object=    (HashMap) list.getItemAtPosition(info.position);`